# Use Get-NetConnectionProfile and Set-NetConnectionProfile to change NetworkCategory

Tags: windows, powershell

I am attempting to write a script that finds all active interfaces and sets their network category to Private. Ideally I would only set interfaces currently set to Public but if I attempt to set connections that are already set I don't imagine that would cause any problems. Here is my humble attempt at this task.

```
get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter -filter "netconnectionstatus = 2" | select netconnectionid, name InterfaceIndex, netconnectionstatus | ForEach-Object Set-NetConnectionProfile -interfaceindex {$_.InterfaceIndex} -NetworkCategory Private
```

Here is the error I receive.

```
ForEach-Object : Input name "Set-NetConnectionProfile" cannot be resolved to a method. At line:1 char:140 + ... ionstatus | ForEach-Object Set-NetConnectionProfile -interfaceindex { ...+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (@{netconnection...ectionstatus=2}:PSObject) [ForEach-Object], PSArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

I am running Powershell 5.0 on Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was right in front of me...

```
Get-NetConnectionProfile | Where-Object { $_.NetworkCategory -match "Public" } | Set-NetConnectionProfile -NetworkCategory Private
```

This can be simplified by filtering in the original get command instead of piping to where:

```
 Get-NetConnectionProfile -NetworkCategory "Public" | Set-NetConnectionProfile -NetworkCategory Private
```

Comment: Just for reference. To change the network category for a given interface (let say interface 77):
    > "Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceIndex 77 -NetworkCategory Private"